# Replace one variable with multiple data

Tags: putty, regex, environment-variables, find-and-replace, sublime-text-3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Servers>
    <Putty>
        <Node Type="1">
            <SavedSession>Default Settings</SavedSession>
            <DisplayName>SAMPLE</DisplayName>
            <ServerName>SAMPLE</ServerName>
            <PuttyConType>4</PuttyConType>
            <Port>22</Port>
            <UserName>root</UserName>
            <Password>whatever</Password>
            <PasswordDelay>0</PasswordDelay>
            <CLParams>SAMPLE -ssh -P 22 -l root</CLParams>
            <ScriptDelay>0</ScriptDelay>
        </Node>
    </Putty>
</Servers>
```

This is the output from MTPuTTy in XML format.

I have a list of IPs in txt format one per line, what I want to is replace SAMPLE with each line so e.g. the list is like that

```
198.168.1.1
198.168.1.2
198.168.1.3
```

I want the output to be like that

```
<Node Type="1">
    <DisplayName>198.168.1.1</DisplayName>
    <ServerName>198.168.1.1</ServerName>
    <CLParams>198.168.1.1 -ssh -P 22 -l root</CLParams>
</Node>

<Node Type="2">
    <DisplayName>198.168.1.2</DisplayName>
    <ServerName>198.168.1.2</ServerName>
    <CLParams>198.168.1.2 -ssh -P 22 -l root</CLParams>
</Node>

<Node Type="3">
    <DisplayName>198.168.1.3</DisplayName>
    <ServerName>198.168.1.3</ServerName>
    <CLParams>198.168.1.3 -ssh -P 22 -l root</CLParams>
</Node>
```

**I have omitted the lines that haven't changed for simplification.**

How can I automate that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex Search and Replace.

Search for

```
^([0-9.]+\.([0-9]+))$
```

Replace with

```
<Node Type="$2">
    <DisplayName>$1</DisplayName>
    <ServerName>$1</ServerName>
    <CLParams>$1 -ssh -P 22 -l root</CLParams>
</Node>
```

Use Ctrl-Enter to enter newline.

Comment: I think this regex is better: `([1-9]{1,3}\.){3}[1-9]`

Comment: How is it better? How will you use it for substitution? What if one of the IPs is 192.168.1.33?

Comment: Your one didn't work at all when I tested it. I meant `([1-9]{1,3}\.){3}[1-9]{1,3}`

Comment: I ran it in Sublime Text 3 build 3126 and it worked fine. Did you set Regex mode in the Find/Replace?

Comment: I used regexr.com

Comment: I don't find most online systems a good way to test Regex especially when multiple lines are involved unless you are very aware of the nuances of various Regex engines. Since Sublime Text 3 is how the question is tagged, I tested in that. In regexr, for example, you need to turn on multiline and put in \n for the newlines in the replacement text: http://regexr.com/3gj6i